How can I get a 1:1 image of the Apple logo on black background how it appears when booting?
I really like the “wallpaper” of the splash screen(consisting of the white Apple logo against the black background) that you see when the OS is starting up. I want to make this my actual desktop wallpaper. But I want it in 1:1 pixel perfect resolution so that it appears to transition seamleasly when logging in and maintains the clarity of the original. I tried using a virtual machine and taking a screenshot but for some reason it doesnt look the same. Any ideas? (I have a Macbook Pro M1)

There might be press material on apple.com which might include an image.
